# How should the y-axis be scaled where there is a wide range and negative values?

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataset with a wide range (-2000 to 2000+).  I'd like to represent the data graphically to show the nuances between -10 to 10 and as well as including the very high and low points.

How does one deal with essentially a log scaling need when there are negative numbers?

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(x = 1:60, y = c(1388.1921188416, 5.13513251950019, 
827.385141356164, 347.152382608789, -1403.89132631293, 8.76211249637448, 
-795.604034104261, -6.52369113306083, -1257.14019210194, 576.858422415042, 
-1.75391638950861, 13.0444100974329, 692.699741383389, -31.3737026981493, 
-16.3358600585619, -178.797702509613, -1089.78713334801, 822.819812466614, 
-1.10072632000639, 12.126596251595, -808.777918017241, 1066.25465157156, 
19.8601939749748, -7.55284201506399, -1175.33845398761, 838.980760081785, 
1724.32036644853, 1228.98507114634, -8.06924854490485, 93.0525864303328, 
1113.28360784884, -6.91061238615605, -696.523886307079, 684.285617068634, 
-1110.51600529198, -7.3603606943474, -1684.42839565825, 5.96791703397169, 
-1695.14152478527, -1055.82144863689, 1535.9172224536, 452.161234696421, 
16.1474593758267, -15.7487092201665, 1027.11308500119, -1638.77126683772, 
-1370.72696242305, 6.83928136891623, -677.395071250169, 1426.55227901298, 
-14.7035072016427, -769.104258036886, -2124.40031023234, -1525.37817498722, 
-15.1205390795812, 957.850322143262, 6.77933260529043, -2569.00750768744, 
1307.53891363394, 1855.23119142582)), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Plot:**

```
with(df, plot(x,y))
```

This seems like something that would already have an answer, but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show the nuances between -10 and 10 but also include the more extreme values, it seems like you might want a transform function that will stretch out the middle of the graph (the log transform only stretches out the lower ends). A possible candidate could be the logistic function:

```
y = L / (1+exp(-k(x-x0))
```

where `x0` is the sigmoid midpoint, `L` is the maximum value and `k` controls the steepness of the curve. For simplicity's sake, set `L=1` (transformed values range from 0 to 1) and `x0=0` (sigmoid midpoint at 0).  Then all you need to choose is `k`.

```
x=seq(from=-2500, to=2500, by=10)
plot(c(-2500, 2500), c(0,1), pch=NA, xlab=NA, ylab=NA)
k=0.001
lines(x, 1/(1+exp(-k*x)), col="red")
k=0.002
lines(x, 1/(1+exp(-k*x)), col="blue" )
k=0.01
lines(x, 1/(1+exp(-k*x)), col="green" )
k=0.03
lines(x, 1/(1+exp(-k*x)), col="orange" )
k=0.05
lines(x, 1/(1+exp(-k*x)), col="purple" )
text(-2000, c(1, 0.95, 0.9, 0.85, 0.8), labels=c("k=0.001", "k=0.002", "k=0.01", "k=0.03", "k=0.05"), col=c("red","blue", "green", "orange", "purple")
```

[image: a series of logistic curves with different values of k]

Play around with these values, but if you really want to show -10 to 10 well, you'll need a pretty steep curve. I chose `k=0.05`

Now you can plot the transformed values of y, but the y-axis is non-sensical.

[image: plot of x vs. logistic transform of y]

This is easily fixed by labeling with the untransformed values (spaced correctly, of course). Do this by suppressing the default plotting of the y-axis `yaxt="n"` and adding a new `axis()` command that add ticks at values that you choose.

```
with(df, plot(x, 1/(1+exp(-k*(y))),yaxt="n", ylab="y"))
labs=c(-2500,  -50, -10,  0, 10, 50,  2500)
axis(2, at=1/(1+exp(-k*labs)), labels=labs, las=1, cex=0.8)
```

[image]

It will take some trial and error to pick the best value of k and the values that you want to put tick marks at, but this is a way to spread out the center of your graph while still showing the extreme values.